# Calling a Pyramid view from a Python script

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm working on a system built in Pyramid and one of the views is for importing data. I'd like to make a script that will call that view. I created a console script import_data in my setup.py and that is successfully added to my bin directory. In the import_data function I think I should be using the pyramid.paste bootstrap function, but when I pass the bootstrap function my ini file bootstrap responses with '*** transaction.interfaces.NoTransaction'. I've read that in assigning the bootstrap I must also set the transaction manager but this also returned NoTransaction.

```
from pyramid.paster import bootstrap
def import_data():
    with bootstrap(sys.argv[1]) as env:
        with env['request'].tm:
            # Post request to pyramid view.
```

If anybody could steer me in the right direction I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prequest` to run a "request" from commandline,
altenatively look at:

https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid-cookiecutter-starter/blob/latest/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/sqlalchemy_scripts/initialize_db.py#L28

For an example of a script that touches database.